# Change UIScrollView with UIBarButton

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uibarbuttonitem

Im trying to have an array of images that i can change with buttons ("Previous" and "Next") that are held inside the navigation bar.

Im tryin to understand how to make this possible, whilst still maintaining a smooth sliding animation between the two.

Ive google pagecontrol, uiscrollview, uibarbutton for tips but to no avail.

If anyone saw the example iPad app for the "Customizing UIKit Appearance" in the WWDC2011 video on iTunes U, thats pretty much exactly what im trying to do.

Any tips appreciated

Answer (score 1):

**in .h file**

dont forgot to `"#import QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"`

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *imgV;
NSArray *arrimages;
int count;

-(IBAction)buttonTap:(UIButton*)sender;
```

**in .m file**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    count = 0;
    arrimages = "init array of images here";

}

-(IBAction)buttonTap:(UIButton*)sender{

    CATransition *tr=[CATransition  animation];
    float dur = 0.50;//1.00-(0.25*Stage);
    tr.duration= dur;
    tr.timingFunction=[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    tr.type=kCATransitionPush;  
    tr.delegate=self;
    if (sender.tag > 0 && [arrimages count]-1 > count) {
        count++;
        imgV.image = [arrimages objectAtIndex:count];
        tr.subtype=kCATransitionFromRight;
        [imgV.layer addAnimation:tr forKey:nil];
    }else if (count > 0 && sender.tag == 0) {
        count--;
        imgV.image = [arrimages objectAtIndex:count];
        tr.subtype=kCATransitionFromLeft;
        [imgV.layer addAnimation:tr forKey:nil];
    }

}
```

**in .xib file**

put 2 UIButtons and UIImageView.

connect touchupinside methode of both buttons to buttonTap action.

connect IBOutlet of imageview.

Answer (score 0):

in scroll view method DidEndScrollingAnimation is the one important method you can call this method when click the button for scroll view properties and method please refer this link http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html